# Understanding example

Tags: real-analysis, differential

I am struggling to understand/visualize the following graph/text. The topic is how the components of the directional derivative along u do not need to have any connection between each other.

**Text:** Take the plane $R^2$ and $y=(0,0)$ and define $f(r \cos( \theta), r\sin \theta) = rg(\theta)$ for any function $ g(\theta)$ that is odd, $ g(-\theta)= -g(\theta)$. Then $d_uf(0,0)= g(\theta)$ if $u=(cos(\theta),sin(\theta))$. The function f is linear along each line through the origin, but the slopes are unrelated.

**Definition:** $d_uf(y)=\lim_{t\to 0}(f(y+tu)-f(y))/t$. $(d_uf(y))_k$ is the kth component of $d_uf(y)$.
If $f:D\to R^m$ with $D\subsetneq R^n$ is differentiable at y with differetial $df(y)$, then $d_uf$ exists at y for any u in $R^n$ and $d_uf(y)=df(y)u$.

**My thoughts**: I understand the idea that the directional derivative in some direction u can be calculated by the components of u in the space, and they are individual. When it comes to the example above, I do not quite follow. How does the graph above lock like? So f and g map into $R^2$. When we say $y=(0,0)$, when does f ever take this value? How is it differentiable at y? I do not see how the pieces fit together to claim that the slopes are unrelated.

**New thoughts:** Putting the problem to the side and coming back to it, I still do not get how f can be differentiable at y given that $(r \cos( \theta), r\sin \theta)$ can never equal $(0,0)$ unless $r=0$. What I did consider doing was to set $x = r\cos \theta$ and  $y = r \sin \theta$. And so I want to get that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$. I do not know if this is the right approach, but I do not get any further.

Another thing I thought about was to just directly use the definition, so I would say

$d_uf(y)=\lim_{t\to 0}(f(y+tu)-f(y))/t = \lim_{t\to 0}(f(tcos(\theta),tsin(\theta))-f(0,0))/t = \lim_{t\to 0}(tg(\theta)-f(0,0))/t$.

I do not see however what I can do about $f(0,0)$, but I imagine it is supposed to go to zero somehow, and the t will cancel, so we are left with $g(\theta)$. But my problem goes back to the issue of $f(0,0)$, or in other words $f(y)$. I do not understand this, unless we set r to zero. Upon writing this I wonder if the limit of t going to zero allows us to say $f(0,0) = \lim_{r\to 0}f(rcos(\theta),rsin(\theta)) = \lim_{r\to 0}rg(\theta)=0$. Is this correct?

Thanks!

Comment: It should be $f=r \, g(\theta)$, shouldn't it? (The factor $r$ is missing.)

Comment: I suppose $r>0$ in the definition of $f$? In that case, I get that $f$ is constant along lines through the origin, possibly with a jump discontinuity there. That would mean $f$ is differentiable only if $f=0$.

Comment: Correct! There is a factor r I accidentally omitted. @AaronGoldsmith how do you visualize that? How is f differentiable at y when (r\cos(\theta), r\sin(\theta)) never equals y?

Comment: @HansLundmark I know r is in f, but how do you instinctively know that there should be an r multiplied with g?

Comment: Well, otherwise $f$ would be as described in the comment by Aaron Goldsmith, so it wouldn't have any directional derivatives at all. If $f$ is going to grow linearly as you move outwards from the origin in a given direction (i.e., with a given value of $\phi$ and increasing $r$), then you need a linear factor $r^1$.

Comment: Compare these two example plots (courtesy of Google): [without the factor $r$](https://www.google.com/search?q=plot+x*y%2F%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29) and [with the factor $r$](https://www.google.com/search?q=plot+sqrt%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29*x*y%2F%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29).